# How does Adapter Design Pattern work in C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, adapter

I have here an example of an adapter pattern(Yes you can check if it was implemented properly), but my real question is here, it is said that Adapter Design Pattern does the following: "Converts the interface of a class into another interface clients expect. Adapter lets classes work together that couldn’t otherwise because of incompatible interfaces." But I'm a bit confused on that statement, I don't quite get so based on my code below, I want to know where it occurred.

Here are my classes/Interface:

```
public interface ILogger
{
      void Write(string data);
}

public class InfrastructureDebugLogger : ILogger
{
      public void Write(string data)
      {
           Debug.WriteLine(data);
      }
}

public class InfrastructureLoggerToDatabaseAdapter : ILogger
{
      private IRepository<Log> adaptee;

      public InfrastructureLoggerToDatabaseAdapter(IRepository<Log> adaptee)
      {
            this.adaptee = adaptee;
      }

      public void Write(string data)
      {
            var log = new Log() { Value = data };
            adaptee.Create(log);   
      }
}

public interface IRepository<T>
{
        void Create(T item);
        void Update(T item);
        T Find(int id);

}

public class Log
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class LogRepository : IRepository<Log>
{
        public void Create(Log item)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Created an item inside the LogRepository");
        }

        public void Update(Log item)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Log Find(int id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

            ILogger logger = new InfrastructureDebugLogger();
            Console.Write("Data: ");
            string data = Console.ReadLine();
            logger.Write(data);
            InfrastructureLoggerToDatabaseAdapter loggerToDatabaseAdapter = 
                new InfrastructureLoggerToDatabaseAdapter(new LogRepository());
            loggerToDatabaseAdapter.Write(data);
            Console.ReadKey();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Your adapter InfrastructureLoggerToDatabaseAdapter is actually named incorrectly. It is taking in an object of type IRepository and converting it into an ILogger type. So it should actually be called DatabaseToInfrastructureLoggerAdapter or more precisely RepositoryToLoggerAdapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it in simple words -

1. Rename your adapter because its not really a InfrastructureLoggerToDatabaseAdapter instead its a Repository to Logger type. Since you are passing a IRepository type object and expecting it to behave like an ILogger.
2. Since the repository have now been updated converted into an ILog type object you should use an ILogger variable to operate on it.

Code:

```
public class RepositoryToLoggerAdapter : ILogger
    {
        private IRepository adaptee;

        public InfrastructureLoggerToDatabaseAdapter(IRepository adaptee)
        {
            this.adaptee = adaptee;
        }

        public void Write(string data)
        {
            var log = new Log() { Value = data };
            adaptee.Create(log);   
        }
    }

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ILogger logger = new InfrastructureDebugLogger();
            Console.Write("Data: ");

            string data = Console.ReadLine();

      //This step is redundant as the text will be shown on the screen as you type
logger.Write(data);

//Create an object of IRepository type.
IRepository repository= new LogRepository();

//The create method works as it should
repository.Create(data);


//You could not have stored the repository object in the logger variable if you did not have this adapter.

            logger = new RepositoryToLoggerAdapter(repository);

//Effectively you now are calling the Create method of the Repository by calling the Write method of the logger.

            logger.Write(data);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Hope this makes sense. Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Thank you for that solution, it was explained very well. Just have one question, would there be a difference if I do something like this: logger = new RepositoryToLoggerAdapter(new LogRepository()) since LogRepository implements IRepository?

Comment: Sure go ahead. I just wrote it so that its easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Your code shows the adapter, but doesn't show *using* it as an adapter.

In order to use this adapter, you'd need to use your `LogRepository`, which implements `IRepository<Log>`, as an `ILogger` via the adapter.  Something like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.Write("Data: ");
        string data = Console.ReadLine();
        InfrastructureLoggerToDatabaseAdapter loggerToDatabaseAdapter = 
            new InfrastructureLoggerToDatabaseAdapter(new LogRepository());

        // Here, you're using a IRepository<Log>, but adapting it to be used as an ILogger...
        ILogger logger = loggerToDatabaseAdapter;
        logger.Write(data);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Converts the interface of a class into another interface clients expect. Adapter lets classes work together that couldn’t otherwise because of incompatible interfaces.

In this case you have an `IRepository<Log>`, but you need to to be an `ILogger`, i.e. "another interface clients expect". The adaptor class allows this by encapsulating the `IRepository<Log>` and translating `ILogger` calls into `IRepository<Log>` calls.

Answer (score 0):

That's not clear from your example, because you don't have clients which require logger. Consider following class:

```
public class Foo
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public Foo(ILogger logger)
    {
         _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Bar()
    {
       _logger.Write("Bar is called");
       // do something
    }
}
```

You can't pass `LogRepository` to this class. Because `LogRepository` does not implement `ILogger` interface. But with adapter you can 'convert' `IRepository<Log>` interface to `ILogger` interface required by `Foo` class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // you can't pass repository to Foo
        LogRepository repository = new LogRepository();            

        InfrastructureLoggerToDatabaseAdapter loggerToDatabaseAdapter = 
            new InfrastructureLoggerToDatabaseAdapter(repository);

        // but you can pass adapter
        Foo foo = new Foo(loggerToDatabaseAdapter);
        foo.Bar();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Actual work still done by `LogRepository` class. Adapter just adapts it's interface to interface required by client. Same way outlet adapters work. If you have electric razor which should be plugged into US outlet, you can't use it in Europe without adapter.